# How different are the elf and human sides?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've just finished the Goth Kids quest, and my next quest is to pick a side. I'm curious how different the game plays for the two sides? In particular, my brother and I are both playing the game independently, and I'd like to know if we pick different sides, we'll be confused when talking to each other.

With as few spoilers as possible, please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They're basically identical.

Aside from the buddies available to you during the school invasion, events play out essentially identically.

Comment: Yep this is correct, an extra tip I could give is save right before you pick so you can reload and get both the achievements.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that will be different is a brief buddy selection, one fight, and one or 2 cut scenes. Nothing major, no effect on the game play at all, just depends on who you want to make mad for a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been said, you get a different weapon as reward:

**Elves:** *Butters' Hammer of Storms*

- 122-170 (3x)
- Shock dmg +50

**Humans:** *Stan's Slashing Blade of the Ranger*

- 180-250 (x2)
- Target starts bleeding on Perfect Attack
- A Perfect Attack targets everyone in a column.